# How to read the Base Framing Protocol of RFC6455?

Tags: websocket

My reference are:

1. [Writing a WebSocket server in Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java)
2. [Base Framing Protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-5.2)

[image: Decoding messages]

Why the first byte `129` represent `FIN`, `RSV1`, `RSV2`, `RSV3`, and `Opcode`?

My expected result are:

1. The first byte is the `FIN` / 1  bit, `RSV1` / 1 bit, `RSV2` / 1 bit, `RSV3` / 1 bit, `Opcode` / 1 bit, `Mask` / 1 bit. Total 9 bits.
2. The second byte is the `Payload length`. Total 7 bits.

My actual result are:

1. The first byte represent `FIN`, `RSV1`, `RSV2`, `RSV3`, and `Opcode`.
2. The second byte represent the `Payload length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to illustrate a bit.

First Byte:
Leftmost bit is the **fin-bit** rightmost 4 bits represents the ***opcode***,
in this case **1**=text

**1**000***0001***

Second Byte:
Leftmost bit indicates if data is **masked** remaining seven indicate the **length**

**1*****0000000***    here the lenght is *zero*
**1*****1111101*** here the lenght is exactly *125*

**1*****1111110*** here the lenght indicator is 126 therefor the next **two** bytes will give you the length  followed by **four** bytes for the mask-key

**1*****1111111*** here the lenght indicator is 127 therefor the next **eight** bytes will give you the length followed by **four** bytes for the mask-key

After all this follows the masked payload.

**ADDED 2021-07-19**

To extract information like opcode and length, you have to apply some bit operations on the given bytes.

Below is an extraction from
https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer/blob/master/server/RFC6455.php to show how the server decodes a frame.

```
public function Decode($frame) {
        // detect ping or pong frame, or fragments

        $this->fin = ord($frame[0]) & 128;
        $this->opcode = ord($frame[0]) & 15;
        $length = ord($frame[1]) & 127;

        if ($length <= 125) {
            $moff = 2;
            $poff = 6;
        } else if ($length == 126) {
            $l0 = ord($frame[2]) << 8;
            $l1 = ord($frame[3]);
            $length = ($l0 | $l1);
            $moff = 4;
            $poff = 8;
        } else if ($length == 127) {
            $l0 = ord($frame[2]) << 56;
            $l1 = ord($frame[3]) << 48;
            $l2 = ord($frame[4]) << 40;
            $l3 = ord($frame[5]) << 32;
            $l4 = ord($frame[6]) << 24;
            $l5 = ord($frame[7]) << 16;
            $l6 = ord($frame[8]) << 8;
            $l7 = ord($frame[9]);
            $length = ( $l0 | $l1 | $l2 | $l3 | $l4 | $l5 | $l6 | $l7);
            $moff = 10;
            $poff = 14;
        }

        $masks = substr($frame, $moff, 4);
        $data = substr($frame, $poff, $length); // hgs 30.09.2016
        $text = '';
        $m0 = $masks[0];
        $m1 = $masks[1];
        $m2 = $masks[2];
        $m3 = $masks[3];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length;) {
            $text .= $data[$i++] ^ $m0;
            if ($i < $length) {
                $text .= $data[$i++] ^ $m1;
                if ($i < $length) {
                    $text .= $data[$i++] ^ $m2;
                    if ($i < $length) {
                        $text .= $data[$i++] ^ $m3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $text;
    }
```

In https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer/blob/master/phpClient/websocketCore.php you will find encode and decode for the client.

Comment: I have 3 questions, I will separate it into 3 comments. First of all, I don't get it. The current way I know how to read the frame data is byte by byte, not bit by bit. In this case, the second byte, `11111101` equals to `253` instead of `125`. Am I right?

Comment: 2nd, in the RFC, `If 127, the following 8 bytes interpreted as a 64-bit unsigned integer (the most significant bit MUST be 0) are the payload length.`. Why it's **four** bytes instead of **eight** bytes?

Comment: 3rd, how to send frame data without the masking key, from client to the server? I assume the second byte has to have value less than 128 or `127, 126 ...`. Meaning the payload length has to be between 0 and 127. However, I tested it with a payload of `abcdef` which means the payload length is 6. Why the second byte is `134` instead of `6`?

Comment: 4th, how to calculate the `EXTENDED_PAYLOAD_LENGTH` if the `PAYLOAD_LENGTH` equals to `126` or `127`?, In the RFC, if it's `126`, the next **two** bytes is the `EXTENDED_PAYLOAD_LENGTH`. Assuming it's 8 bit per byte. The **first** and **second** next bytes could be between `0 - 255`. Does this mean the actual maximum payload length is `255` + `255` if the second byte equals to `126`?