# How to calculate the EXTENDED_PAYLOAD_LENGTH if the PAYLOAD_LENGTH is 126 in a WebSocket frame data?

Tags: websocket, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

My goal is calculate the payload length of a message sent by a client to the server through the WebSocket protocol.

I am using RFC6455 as a reference.

```
 The length of the "Payload data", in bytes: if 0-125, that is the
      payload length.  If 126, the following 2 bytes interpreted as a
      16-bit unsigned integer are the payload length.  If 127, the
      following 8 bytes interpreted as a 64-bit unsigned integer (the
      most significant bit MUST be 0) are the payload length.
```

Here is a sample of frame data of message `abcdef` from a client to the server.

```
129 134 167 225 225 210 198 131 130 182 194 135
```

What if, the **second** byte value is `254`, in this case `254 - 128` equals to `126`.

```
129 254 167 225 225 210 198 131 130 182 194 135
```

I am assuming the **third** and **fourth** byte are the `EXTENDED_PAYLOAD_LENGTH`. In this case, because the **second** byte - 128 equals to 126, the `EXTENDED_PAYLOAD_LENGTH` is the actual payload length.

However, in the RFC, it specifically says `16-bit` instead of the next **two** bytes.

```
If 126, the following 2 bytes interpreted as a
      16-bit unsigned integer are the payload length.
```

How do you combine the **third** and **fourth** byte to get the actual payload length? In this case, I wrote the code in Java, and currently I don't have access to read the frame data bit by bit, instead I read it byte by byte.

PS: I am thinking to use bitwise operators, am I going to the right direction?

Comment: See my extended answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427402/how-to-read-the-base-framing-protocol-of-rfc6455

Comment: @Heinz `$l0 = ord($frame[2]) << 8; $l1 = ord($frame[3]); $length = ($l0 | $l1);` in other words, in bitwise operations, `(byte1 << 8) | byte2)`.